# RX getting a IObservable<List<T>> to an IObservable<T>

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, system.reactive

I'm pretty new to RX and cannot figure this out.

I have an `IObservable<List<T>>` where `List<T>` is guaranteed to have one element.

How do I convert this to an `IObservable<T>`.

I thought it would have something to do with `Single` but that is listed as obsolete, and also doesn't return an `IObservable<T>` anyway (as pretty sure it would return the `Single` `List<T>` element.

Is there some `SelectMany` magic I can do here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just do this:

```
IObservable<List<T>> source;

var converted = source.Select(x => x[0]);
```

Or if you prefer LINQ query comprehension syntax then equivalent is:

```
var converted = from x in source select x[0];
```

Comment: nice, thanks..that was easy, keep confusing myself with this stuff :(